# call function which changes an IBoutlet

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet

Im calling a function in Class B which is in Class A:

```
ClassA *object = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    [object changemethod];
    [object release];
```

In Class A:

```
-(void)changemethod{
[imageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"]];
NSLog(@"Works");
}
```

Calling the function in Class A works fine (I get the Logmessage) but the "imageView" is not changing the image. Why? Any clue?

Comment: What's really `ClassA`? My guess, it's not the same object that's on the screen and you're just creating a new object...

Comment: What do you mean by "really ClassA"? How can I change the "real" imageView of ClassA?

Comment: Is ClassA a UIView or a UIViewController?  How did you put ClassA on the screen, from storyboard, from a nib, or using code?

Comment: Its a UIView Controller. imageView is put on screen via storyboard. I´ll try it using code...

Comment: Adding the UIImageView programmatically didn´t make it work. What´s wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution for my problem. I changed the "changemethod" to a class method. And to access the IBImageView in the class method I put it before the "@implementation". The IBImageView gets added in the "viewDidLoad" method and then changed by calling the classmethod "changemethod". Thanks.